# Apply an Excel array formula with a custom VBA function

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, array-formulas

I'm trying to use [Excel array formulae](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) for summing up the number of cells in a columnar range (an array if you will), which have a background color.

This working function checks whether a cell has a background color:

```vb
Function FillIndicator(color As Range) As Integer
If color.Interior.ColorIndex = -4142 Then
    FillIndicator = 0
Else
    FillIndicator = 1
End If
End Function
```

If I were to eschew array formulae, and my range were, say, C5:C7, I would write something like:

```
=FillIndicator(C5) + FillIndicator(C6) + FillIndicator(C7)
```

My attempt at using an array formula:

```
=SUM(FillIndicator(C5:C7))
```

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> gets me a `#VALUE` error.

Note: I think I'm using Excel 365 version 2208.

Comment: For a detailed discussion of returning an array from a function, see the late Chip Pearsons article (***especially the 2nd half***) on [Passing and Returning Arrays from Functions](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/PassingAndReturningArrays.htm)

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible to call scalar user-defined functions on multi-cell ranges like this. One solution would be to return an array from your VBA function instead of a scalar value.

Comment: @NeilT: Can you expand your comment into an answer? Or should I just follow the link Ron Rosenfeld suggested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is the same as @RicardinhoL answer with three small differences: 1) use an Optional color parameter with default value that you use in question 2) check if range is nothing else an error occurs 3) use as counter the name of the function, since it works like a variable itself.

Must to return Long because there are many-many cells in excel!

```
Public Function CountIfColor(rngClr As Range, Optional thisColor As Long = -4142) As Long
   Dim r As Range
   If Not rngClr Is Nothing Then
      For Each r In rngClr
         If r.Interior.ColorIndex = thisColor Then CountIfColor = CountIfColor + 1
      Next
   End If
End Function
```

Comment: I wouldn't name it quite like that, but - this works nicely. Too bad I can't use a proper array function.

Comment: You need an "array function". QUESTION: Suppose we have three cells A1:A3 with the color we are looking for. You want to put a formula in B1 with Ctrl-Shift+Enter and drag it until B3. What values expect in B1, B2 B3 cells?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need to count cells or ranges of specific columns.

```html
Function SumCellsByColor(colorRange As Range, targetColor As Long) As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim count As Long
    
    count = 0
    
    For Each cell In colorRange
        If cell.Interior.color = targetColor Then
            count = count + 1
        End If
    Next cell
    
    SumCellsByColor = count
End Function


Sub ExampleUsage()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim count As Long
    
    ' Define the range of cells in which you want to count
    Set rng = Range("A18:C22")
    
    ' Call the SumCellsByColor function and pass the range and target color.
    count = SumCellsByColor(rng, RGB(255, 0, 0)) ' For example, the color red
    
    ' Print the result
    MsgBox "Number of cells with red color: " & count
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

To have the UDF return an array, you merely need to set the array equal to the function in the return line.

For example, given your apparent desire to return a boolean array corresponding to whether or not the cells in a range are colored:

```
Option Explicit

Function FillIndicator(color As Range)
    Dim v  'variable to loop through array
    Dim al As Object 'collect the test results
    
Set al = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

'run the test on each cell
For Each v In color
    al.Add v.Interior.ColorIndex <> -4142
Next v

'Set the Function equal to an array
FillIndicator = al.toarray

End Function
```

Note the penultimate line where `FillIndicator` is set equal to the array.

The formula will return an array of `TRUE/FALSE` depending on the `Interior.ColorIndex` property.

You can then treat this the same as any other array function.